# Can I use the mixin pattern with setters and getters

Tags: javascript

```
;
"use strict";
function IPoint() {

  this.getDistance = function(point) {
    var x = this.x - point.x;
    var y = this.y - point.y;
    return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
  };

  this.isAbove = function(point) {
    if (this.y <= point.y) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
  this.isBelow = function(point) {
    if (this.y >= point.y) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
  this.isLeftOf = function(point) {
    if (this.x <= point.x) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
  this.isRightOf = function(point) {
    if (this.x >= point.x) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
};

var Point = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  IPoint.call(this);
};
Point.prototype =
  Object.create(null,
                {
                  get x() {
                    return this._x;
                  },
                  set x(v) {
                    this._x = v;
                  },
                  get y() {
                    return this._y;
                  },
                  set y(v) {
                    this._y = v;
                  },
                });
```

Gives me the error *Uncaught TypeError: Property description must be an object: undefined geometry.js:47 (anonymous function)*. This gives me the impression that I can't use setters and getters in the object I pass in the dot.create but I have no idea why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not related to your question, but: a) there's no reason to use getters/setters like this b) the `IPoint` mixin should be applied to the prototype. No need to make those methods instance properties.

Comment: What do you mean by those methods?

Comment: The methods like `getDistance`, `is[inDirectionOf]` etc.

Comment: My idea is to have an interface 'object' that I can mixin different interfaces for different objects. In this case I have an object conforming to only one interface. What should they be instead?

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to recreate the functions for every instance. Optimally they should be existing only once and being referenced from each object.

Comment: Ok I see your point. Would you be so kind to provide a code example or  an light description of what would be a better way to implement mixins/interfaces in javascript? I'm trying to learn better the dark corners of the language that I have avoided until now.

Comment: Check http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#mixinpatternjavascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) does take an object of [*property descriptors*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2FdefineProperty#Description) as its second argument, like [`defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) does. The correct syntax would be

```
Point.prototype = Object.create(null, {
    x: {
        get: function() { return this._x; },
        set: function(v) { this._x = v; },
        // configurable: true,
        // enumerable: true
    },
    x: {
        get: function() { return this._y; },
        set: function(v) { this._y = v; },
        // configurable: true,
        // enumerable: true
    }
});
```

However, I don't see a reason why `Point`s should not inherit from `Object`, so just make it

```
Point.prototype = {
    get x() { return this._x; },
    set x(v) { this._x = v; },
    get y() { return this._y; },
    set y(v) { this._y = v; }
};
```

Comment: It should inherit from `IPoint` and remove the `IPoint.call` :P

Comment: @Esailija: You mean `IPoint.call(Point.prototype);`? Or `Object.create(new IPoint, …)`? I thought it was supposed to be a mixin

Comment: Does mixin mean pointless duplication of functions on the objects? You said it yourself that it should be applied on the prototype

Comment: If implemented improperly, it could mean that. It should be meaningful duplication of properties only :-) OP's constructor-like `IPoint` implementation doesn't do that of course, but I only wanted to answer about the `Object.create` mistake not his mixin pattern.